# Second level of menu in specific div with alight to left

Tags: html, css, menu, jquery-animate

At the beginning I want to say that I'm Polish, and my english is not the best.
I'm  making my own site and I have a problem with my menu. It's very specific because it use auto height and jquery slide to make some nice animation.

My problem is with the "second" level of menu. I need to show description underline of item but at left side of page.

HTML Is fine

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>1. Item
            <h3>1. item description</h3>
        </li>

        <li>2. Item
            <h3>2. item description</h3>
        </li>

        <li>3. Item
            <h3>3. item description</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I think that the problem is in CSS and some DOM settings.
It must be here :

```
nav {
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
nav ul {
    /*don't enter hegiht*/
}
nav ul li {
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:20px 10px 21px 10px;
}
nav ul li h3 {
    display:block;
}
```

and jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("nav h3").hide();
    //hide description

    //show when hover
    $("nav li").hover(function(){
        $("h3", this).slideToggle("slow");

    },function(){
        $("h3", this).slideToggle("slow");
    },800);
    return false;


});
```

Comment: I've set up your fragments in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRf98/ . But I don't really see what you want it to do differently. Can you explain a bit more what is wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks for putting the code in to fiddle. 
I want make that description show under menu line on left side. Check differences when you use  
"nav ul li h3 {
    display:block;
}" 

and when you use 

"nav ul li h3 {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DOM elements are nested, their most natural layout is also to show them in that vein. You can work around that by using absolute positioning, but I often lose track of things that way.

I'd split the list that you have into two separate lists:

```
<nav>
    <ul class='top'>
        <li>1. Item</li>
        <li>2. Item</li>
        <li>3. Item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='bottom'>
        <li>1. item description</li>
        <li>2. item description</li>
        <li>3. item description</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

With that in place, the animation becomes a matter of finding the corresponding bottom `li` when the user hovers over a top `li`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("nav ul.bottom li").hide();
    //hide description

    //show when hover
    $("nav ul.top li").hover(function(){
        $("nav ul.bottom li:eq("+$(this).index()+")").slideToggle("slow");

    },function(){
        $("nav ul.bottom li:eq("+$(this).index()+")").slideToggle("slow");
    },800);
    return false;

});
```

I used this additional CSS:

```
nav ul.bottom li {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;            
    display:block;
}
```

The updated Fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/GRf98/2/

Comment: OK. Please upvote any answer that helped you and click the check mark next to the one that worked best. It's how others who have similar problems will know which answers are most valuable.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution creates another problem. When you open a description, you cannot focus cursor on it, because as you leave the item list you close description.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by: "I need to show description underline of item but at left side of page."

This will place the descriptions at the left side of the page:

```
 nav ul li h3 {
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;            
        display:block;
    }​
```

Comment: yep that is some solution but when i use "position:absolute" the div is not change size.